# Messaging inside Chrome Extension in ClojureScript

Tags: google-chrome-extension, clojurescript

I'm trying to write a Chrome extension with some basic communication between content script and background page.

In Javascript i would register listeners in both content and background pages, for example in a background page:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // Send a message to the active tab
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    var activeTab = tabs[0];
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "clicked_browser_action"});
  });
});
```

(taken from [this tutorial](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-make-a-chrome-extension)).

Another example that works in Javascript:

```
// content.js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({screenShot: true}, function(response) {
  console.log("response: " + response);
});

// background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    alert('message received!');
    console.log("request: " + request);
    if (request.screenShot) {
      // do something
    }
});
```

How can i translate the above code to ClojureScript?

My first attempt was to create a project based on [lein-chrome-extension](https://github.com/clumsyjedi/lein-chrome-extension) template and use [Khroma](https://github.com/suprematic/khroma)'s `runtime/connect` methods that rely on core-async. But i don't get proper communication between `content.cljs` and `background.cljs` scripts. In `content.cljs` i have:

```
(defn init []
  (go
    (let [bg (runtime/connect)]
      (console/log "content script test")
      (while true
        (>! bg :lol-i-am-a-content-script)
        (console/log "Background said: " (<! bg))))))
```

and in `background.cljs`:

```
(defn on-connect-listener []
  (console/log "on-connect-listener")
  (go-loop 
    [channel (runtime/on-connect)]
    (let [content (<! channel)]
      (console/log "Content script said: " (<! content))
      (>! content :fml-i-am-the-background-script)
      (recur channel))))
```

(defn init []
  (on-connect-listener))

In Chrome console i get only "Background said: fml-i-am-the-background-script" messages, therefore only messages sent by background to content page, but not vice versa (i would have expected "Content script said: lol-i-am-a-content-script" as well).

Most probably i am making some obvious mistake(s) here. Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show any attempts and how they fail?

Comment: @Xan - Extended my original question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Two weeks ago I started working on a chrome extension in ClojureScript. I started using Khroma and I had no problem in using their library to achieve two-way communication between my background page and content script (or my background page and popup button page). So I can confirm that the library works. Unfortunately, I don't see any obvious mistake in your code examples here.

As a side note: I didn't like how Khorma "abused" code.async channels to implement duplex communication. Khroma gives you channel-like object upon connection. By putting a message on it you send the message and by taking a message from it you wait to receive a message. Easy? But this is not really the core.async channel contract. Normally in core.async putting and taking operates on **the same queue** and it can be done **by anyone** (producer or consumer). Khroma effectively turned it into a "channel" which has two queues inside. One for sending and one for receiving. If you put something on channel, you cannot take it back (for example). That was really confusing for me at first. And I think it confuses you as well, a code like this is hard to read:

```
(let [content (<! channel)]
      (console/log "Content script said: " (<! content))
      (>! content :fml-i-am-the-background-script))
```

The problem is >! which never blocks (In Khroma case putting means sending and that is a non-blocking function call and has nothing to do with the channel). But <! can "block" if there is no message available on the channel.

So I decided to write my own library to replace Khroma. Not only to fix this minor design flaw, but mainly because I wanted to auto-generate the library from chromium sources, so it covers all APIs automatically.

The library is called Chromex and I have just released a simple Chrome extension sample project along with some documentation: https://github.com/binaryage/chromex-sample

The code for background page looks like this:
https://github.com/binaryage/chromex-sample#background-page

Note that I also wrap `runtime.Port` as core.async-like channel, but I don't pretend two-way communication. You can only take! from the channel to receive a message (channel wrapper implements only core-async/ReadPort protocol). To post a message you have to use a separate `post-message!` protocol method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm working through your examples.